# Spreading a dataframe with transpose

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Suppose I have the below data frame

```
ID <- c("Tom" , "Tom", "Ana", "Ana", "Lena", "Lena")
Use <- c("F", "T", "T", "F", "T", "T")
df <- data.frame(ID, Use)
```

and I would like to get a new data frame where each row is a person and each column is Use1, Use2 for the person. (each person is associated with 2 uses)

i.e. I would et

```
Use1 <- c("F" , "T", "T")
Use2 <- c("T", "F", "T")
df_wanted <- data.frame(Use1, Use2)
```

Then ideally the row.names would be the names of the persons in order so "Tom" for row 1, "Ana" for row 2 and "Lena" for row 3.

How can I do this? i tried `gather`, `spread`, `melt` but can't seem to figure out a way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution. I just thought I would explain `names_glue` argument:

- You can try the solution without `names_glue` argument and you will see your new column names will end up like `1` & `2`. But if you would like to create a custom name for your reshaped data set you could use `.value` argument in `glue` syntax. In this way we put variable names into braces `{}` so that they are evaluated as R code. Here we specified that we first want the name of the column in `df` where we take our values from (`Use`), then the values of `id` column. We could make other modifications as well like putting underscore etc

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = Use, names_glue = "{.value}{id}")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    Use1  Use2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Tom   F     T    
2 Ana   T     F    
3 Lena  T     T
```

Comment: an amazing answer!! +1

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Onyambu, you are always one of my biggest inspiration here.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
df_wanted <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, split(df$Use, df$ID)))
names(df_wanted) <- c('Use1', 'Use2')
#      Use1 Use2
# Ana     T    F
# Lena    T    T
# Tom     F    T
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID ~ paste0("Use", rowid(ID)), value.var = 'Use')
```

-output

```
      ID Use1 Use2
1:  Ana    T    F
2: Lena    T    T
3:  Tom    F    T
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyr` variant:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  chop(Use) %>% 
  unnest_wider(Use, names_sep = "")
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    Use1  Use2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Tom   F     T    
2 Ana   T     F    
3 Lena  T     T
```

Comment: Nice function `chop` never heard of that before.

Comment: It's like `nest` but uses a `list` instead of a `tibble`.